# wxPython Installation failure

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, wxpython

I am trying to install wxPython on a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 using the command

```
pip3 install wxPython
```

The build fails with

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/wx/libwx_baseu-3.0.so'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-30uqzd2e/wxPython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hynl659w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-30uqzd2e/wxPython/
```

I have no idea where to look for a solution. Can someone please suggest where I might start

[EDIT 20200424 08:06]

I looked in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

and

```
libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
```

was absent. I have installed it from [this site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libwxbase3.0-0v5/download)

It is now present, but the install fails with the same message

Comment: I was looking for a solution few hours today! Finally I decided to install it in virtualenv with python 2.7. No problems at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to install wxPython.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and performed the following:

```
sudo apt install make gcc libgtk-3-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev python-gst-1.0 python3-gst-1.0 libglib2.0-dev ubuntu-restricted-extras libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
pip3 install wxpython
```

I guess that when it was failing I had tried many fixes and somewhere along the line something was corrupted or there was a mismatch somewhere.

My solution was based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073145/how-to-install-wxpython-4-ubuntu-18-04/1073183#1073183)

Answer (score 2):

I Installed wx.python 4.1.0 yesterday with:

```
URL=https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk2/ubuntu-18.04
pip install -U -f $URL wxPython
```

See: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/ for details.

For gtk3 simply replace `gtk2` in the url above.

Comment: I also installed yesterday, following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073145/how-to-install-wxpython-4-ubuntu-18-04/1073183#1073183). This was after a complete re-install of 18.04. I think on earlier tries I must have corrupted or conflicted some libraries

Comment: So are you in the happy state of being able to use or not. That answer seems to be a rather long winded method.

Comment: Yes happy. used "sudo apt install make gcc libgtk-3-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev python-gst-1.0 python3-gst-1.0 libglib2.0-dev ubuntu-restricted-extras libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev" and "pip3 install wxpython". Works perfectly. Thanks you. I'll add my own answer for clarity